# Single Task Taking Long Time in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a PySpark application where I am reading several Parquet files into Spark dataframes and created temporary views on them to use in my SQL query. So I have like 18 views where some are ~ 1TB, few in several GBs and some other smaller views. I am joining all of these and running my business logic to get the desired outcome. My code takes extremely long time to run (>3 hours) for this data. Looking at the Spark History Server, I can see there's one task that seems the culprit as the time taken, data spilled to memory and disk, shuffle read/write everything is way higher than the median. This indicates a data skew. So I even used salting on my large dataframes before creating the temp views. However there's still no difference in the execution time. I checked the number of partitions and it's already 792 (maximum I can have my current Glue config). I have also enabled adaptive query execution and adaptive skewJoin handling.

My original dataset was extremely huge largest table being ~40TB and has 2.5 years of data. I am trying to do a one time historical load and was unsuccessful on running over the entire data. With trial and error, I had to reduce this to processing 1TB of data at a time (for the largest table) which is still taking 3+ hours. This is not a scalable approach and hence I am looking for some inputs to optimize this.

Below are my app details:
Number of workers = 792
Spark config:

```
spark= (SparkSession
.builder
.appName("scmCaseAlertDatamartFullLoad")
.config("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled","true")
.config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout","900")
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled","true")
.getOrCreate()
)
```

**Code (just included key relevant methods, starting point is loadSCMCseAlertData()):**

```
def getIncomingMatchesFullData(self):
        select_query_incoming_matches_full_data = """
        SELECT DISTINCT alrt.caseid             AS case_id,
                alrt.alertid            AS alert_id,
                alrt.accountid          AS account_id,
                sc.created_time         AS case_created_time,
                sc.last_updated_time    AS case_last_updated_time,
                alrt.srccreatedtime     AS alert_created_time,
                aud.last_updated_by     AS case_last_updated_by,
                sc.closed_time          AS case_last_close_time,
                lcs.status              AS case_status,
                lcst.state              AS case_state,
                lcra.responsive_action,
                sc.assigned_to          AS case_assigned_to,
                cr1.team_name           AS case_assigned_to_team,
                sc.resolved_by          AS case_resolved_by,
                cr2.team_name           AS case_resolved_by_team,
                aud.last_annotation     AS case_last_annotation,
                ca.name                 AS case_approver,
                alrt.screeningdecision  AS screening_decision,
                ap.accountpool          AS division,
                lcd.decision            AS case_current_decision,
                CASE
                    WHEN sm.grylaclientid LIKE '%AddressService%' THEN 'Address Service'
                    WHEN sm.grylaclientid LIKE '%GrylaOrderProcessingService%' THEN 'Retail Checkout Service'
                    WHEN sm.grylaclientid = 'urn:cdo:GrylaBatchScreeningAAA:AWS:Default' THEN 'Batch Screening'
                    WHEN sm.grylaclientid = 'urn:cdo:OfficerJennyBindle:AWS:Default' THEN 'API'
                    ELSE 'Other'
                END                 AS channel,
                ap.businesstype         AS business_type,
                ap.businessname         AS business_name,
                ap.marketplaceid        AS ap_marketplace_id,
                ap.region               AS ap_region,
                ap.memberid             AS ap_member_id,
                ap.secondaryaccountpool AS secondary_account_pool,
                sm.action               AS client_action,
                acl.added_by,
                acl.lnb_id              AS accept_list_lnb_id,
                acl.created_time        AS accept_list_created_time,
                acl.source_case_id      AS accept_list_source_case_id,
                acs.status              AS accept_list_status,
                ap.street1              AS ap_line_1,
                ap.street2              AS   ap_line_2,
                ap.street3              AS ap_line_3,
                ap.city                 AS ap_city,
                ap.state                AS ap_state,
                ap.postalcode           AS ap_postal_code,
                ap.country              AS ap_country,
                ap.fullname             AS ap_full_name,
                ap.email                AS ap_email,
                sm.screening_match_id   AS dp_screening_match_id,
                CASE
                    WHEN sm.matchtype = 'name_only_matching_details' THEN 'Name Only'
                    WHEN sm.matchtype = 'address_only_matching_details' THEN 'Address Only'
                    WHEN sm.matchtype = 'address_matching_details' THEN 'Address'
                    WHEN sm.matchtype = 'scr_matching_details' THEN 'SCR'
                    WHEN sm.matchtype = 'hotkey_matching_details' THEN 'HotKey'
                END                 AS match_type,
                sm.matchaction AS match_action,
                alrt.batchfilename      AS batch_file_id,
                REGEXP_REPLACE(dp.name, '\\n|\\r|\\t', ' ')   AS dp_matched_add_full_name,
                dp.street               AS dp_line1,
                ''                  AS dp_line2,
                dp.city                 AS dp_city,
                dp.state                AS dp_state,
                dp.postalcode           AS dp_postal_code,
                dp.country              AS dp_country,
                dp.matchedplaces        AS scr_value,
                dp.hotkeyvalues         AS hotkey_value,
                sm.acceptlistid         AS suppressed_by_accept_list_id,
                sm.suppresseddedupe     AS is_deduped,
                sm.matchhash            AS hash,
                sm.matchdecision        AS match_decision,
                ap.addressid            AS amazon_address_id,
                ap.dateofbirth          AS date_of_birth,
                sm.grylaclientid        AS gryla_client_id,
                cr1.name                AS case_assigned_to_role,
                cr2.name                AS case_resolved_by_role,
                alrt.screeningengine AS screening_engine,
                sm.srccreatedtime     AS match_created_time,
                sm.srclastupdatedtime AS match_updated_time,
                to_date(sm.srclastupdatedtime,"yyyy-MM-dd") AS match_updated_date,
                sm.match_updated_time_msec,
                sm.suppressedby AS match_suppressed_by
FROM 
     cm_screening_match sm
         JOIN
     cm_screening_match_redshift smr ON sm.screening_match_id = smr.screening_match_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_case_alert alrt ON sm.screening_match_id = alrt.screening_match_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_amazon_party ap ON sm.screening_match_id = ap.screening_match_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_denied_party dp ON sm.screening_match_id = dp.screening_match_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_spectre_case sc ON alrt.caseid = sc.case_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_lookup_case_status lcs ON sc.status_id = lcs.status_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_lookup_case_state lcst ON sc.state_id = lcst.state_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_lookup_case_decision lcd ON sc.decision_id = lcd.decision_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_lookup_case_responsive_action lcra ON sc.responsive_action_id = lcra.responsive_action_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_user cu1 ON sc.assigned_to = cu1.alias
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_role cr1 ON cu1.current_role_id = cr1.role_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_user cu2 ON sc.resolved_by = cu2.alias
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_role cr2 ON cu2.current_role_id = cr2.role_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_accept_list acl ON acl.screening_match_id = sm.screening_match_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_lookup_accept_list_status acs ON acs.status_id = acl.status_id
         LEFT JOIN
     (
         SELECT case_id,
                last_value(username) OVER (PARTITION BY case_id ORDER BY created_time
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_updated_by,
                last_value(description) OVER (PARTITION BY case_id ORDER BY created_time
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_annotation
         FROM cm_spectre_case_audit
     ) aud ON sc.case_id = aud.case_id
         LEFT JOIN
     cm_approver ca ON sc.approver_id = ca.approver_id
"""
        print(select_query_incoming_matches_full_data)
        incomingMatchesFullDF = self.spark.sql(select_query_incoming_matches_full_data)
        return incomingMatchesFullDF
 
def getBaseTables(self,matchtime_lower_threshold,matchtime_upper_threshold,cursor):
        print('Fetching datalake data for matches created after: {}' .format(matchtime_lower_threshold))
        
        matchDF = self.getDatalakeData(matchtime_lower_threshold,matchtime_upper_threshold,self.data_input_match)
        matchDF = matchDF.select("screening_match_id","grylaclientid","action","matchtype","matchaction","acceptlistid","suppresseddedupe","matchhash","matchdecision","srccreatedtime","srclastupdatedtime","suppressedby","lastupdatedtime")
        #.withColumn("screentime",to_timestamp("screentime")) \
        matchDF = matchDF.withColumn("match_updated_time_msec",col("lastupdatedtime").cast(LongType())).drop("lastupdatedtime")
        #matchDF = matchDF.repartition(2400,"screening_match_id")
        matchDF = self.getLatestRecord(matchDF) 
        matchDF = matchDF.withColumn("salt", rand())
        matchDF = matchDF.repartition("salt")
        matchDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_screening_match")
        print("Total from matchDF:",matchDF.count())
        print("Number of paritions in matchDF: " ,matchDF.rdd.getNumPartitions())
        
        alertDF = self.getDatalakeData(matchtime_lower_threshold,matchtime_upper_threshold,self.data_input_alert)
        alertDF = alertDF.select("screening_match_id","caseid","alertid","accountid","srccreatedtime","screeningdecision","batchfilename","screeningengine","lastupdatedtime")
        alertDF = alertDF.withColumn("match_updated_time_msec",col("lastupdatedtime").cast(LongType())).drop("lastupdatedtime")
        #alertDF = alertDF.repartition(2400,"screening_match_id")
        alertDF = self.getLatestRecord(alertDF)
        alertDF = alertDF.withColumn("salt", rand())
        alertDF = alertDF.repartition("salt")
        alertDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_case_alert")
        print("Total from alertDF:",alertDF.count())
        print("Number of paritions in alertDF: " ,alertDF.rdd.getNumPartitions())
        
        apDF = self.getDatalakeData(matchtime_lower_threshold,matchtime_upper_threshold,self.data_input_ap)
        apDF = apDF.select("screening_match_id","accountpool","businesstype","businessname","marketplaceid","region","memberid","secondaryaccountpool","street1","street2","street3","city","state","postalcode","country","fullname","email","addressid","dateofbirth","lastupdatedtime")
        apDF = apDF.withColumn("dateofbirth",to_date("dateofbirth","yyyy-MM-dd")) \
                   .withColumn("match_updated_time_msec",col("lastupdatedtime").cast(LongType())) \
                   .drop("lastupdatedtime")
        #apDF = apDF.repartition(2400,"screening_match_id")
        apDF = self.getLatestRecord(apDF)
        apDF = apDF.withColumn("salt", rand())
        apDF = apDF.repartition("salt")
        apDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_amazon_party")
        print("Total from apDF:",apDF.count())
        print("Number of paritions in apDF: " ,apDF.rdd.getNumPartitions())
        
        dpDF = self.getDatalakeData(matchtime_lower_threshold,matchtime_upper_threshold,self.data_input_dp)
        dpDF = dpDF.select("screening_match_id","name","street","city","state","postalcode","country","matchedplaces","hotkeyvalues","lastupdatedtime")
        dpDF = dpDF.withColumn("match_updated_time_msec",col("lastupdatedtime").cast(LongType())).drop("lastupdatedtime")
        #dpDF = dpDF.repartition(2400,"screening_match_id")
        dpDF = self.getLatestRecord(dpDF)
        dpDF = dpDF.withColumn("salt", rand())
        dpDF = dpDF.repartition("salt")
        dpDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_denied_party")
        print("Total from dpDF:",dpDF.count())
        print("Number of paritions in dpDF: " ,dpDF.rdd.getNumPartitions())
        
        print('Fetching data from Redshift Base tables...')
        self.getRedshiftData(matchtime_lower_threshold,matchtime_upper_threshold,cursor)
        
        caseAuditDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_case_audit)
        caseAuditDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_spectre_case_audit")
        
        caseDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_case)
        caseDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_spectre_case")
        
        caseStatusDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_case_status)
        caseStatusDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_lookup_case_status")
        
        caseStateDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_case_state)
        caseStateDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_lookup_case_state")
        
        caseDecisionDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_case_decision)
        caseDecisionDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_lookup_case_decision")
        
        caseRespActDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_case_responsive_action)
        caseRespActDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_lookup_case_responsive_action")
        
        userDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_user)
        userDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_user")
        
        userSnapshotDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_user_snapshot)
        userSnapshotDF.createOrReplaceTempView("v_cm_user_snapshot")
        
        roleDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_role)
        roleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_role")
        
        skillDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_skill)
        skillDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_skill")
        
        lookupSkillDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_lookup_skills)
        lookupSkillDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_lookup_skills")
        
        skillTypeDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_skill_type)
        skillTypeDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_skill_type")
        
        acceptListDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_accept_list)
        acceptListDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_accept_list")
        
        lookupAcceptListStatusDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_lookup_accept_list_status)
        lookupAcceptListStatusDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_lookup_accept_list_status")
        
        approverDF = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_approver)
        approverDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_approver")
        
        screeningMatchDF_temp = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_screening_match_redshift)
        screeningMatchLookupDF_temp = self.spark.read.parquet(self.data_input_lookup_screening_match_redshift)
        screeningMatchLookupDF_temp_new = screeningMatchLookupDF_temp.withColumnRenamed("screening_match_id","lookupdf_screening_match_id")
        
        """
        The screening_match_id in datalake table is a mix of alphanumeric match IDs (the ones in cm_lookup_screening_match_id in Redshift) and numeric (the ones in cm_screening_match in Redshift). Hence we combine the match IDs from both the Redshift tables. Also, there are matches which were created in the past but updated recently. Since updated date is only present in cm_screening_match and not in cm_lookup_screening_match_id, we will only have the numeric match Ids. When we join this to datalake table, we won't be able to find these matches as they are present in the alphanumeric form in datalake. Hence what we do is read the entire table of cm_lookup_screening_match_id and join it with cm_screening_match to enrich cm_screening_match with the alphanumeric match Id. Finally we filter cm_lookup_screening_match_id only for newly created matches and combine with the matches from enriched version of cm_screening_match.
        """
        screeningMatchDF_enriched = screeningMatchDF_temp.join(screeningMatchLookupDF_temp_new,screeningMatchDF_temp.screening_match_id == screeningMatchLookupDF_temp_new.lookupdf_screening_match_id,"left")
        screeningMatchDF_enriched = screeningMatchDF_enriched.withColumn("screening_match_id",col("screening_match_id").cast(StringType()))
        
        screeningMatchDF = screeningMatchDF_enriched.select(col("screening_match_id")).union(screeningMatchDF_enriched.select(col("match_event_id")))
        screeningMatchLookupDF = screeningMatchLookupDF_temp_new.filter("created_time > '{}'" .format(matchtime_lower_threshold)).select(col("match_event_id"))
        
        screeningMatchRedshiftDF = screeningMatchDF.union(screeningMatchLookupDF)
        #screeningMatchRedshiftDF = screeningMatchRedshiftDF.repartition(792,"screening_match_id")
        screeningMatchRedshiftDF = screeningMatchRedshiftDF.withColumn("salt", rand())
        screeningMatchRedshiftDF = screeningMatchRedshiftDF.repartition("salt")
        screeningMatchRedshiftDF.createOrReplaceTempView("cm_screening_match_redshift")
        print("Total from screeningMatchRedshiftDF:",screeningMatchRedshiftDF.count())
 
def loadSCMCaseAlertTable(self):
        print('Getting the thresholds for data to be loaded')
        matchtime_lower_threshold = self.getLowerThreshold('scm_case_alert_data')
        print('Match time lower threshold is: {}' .format(matchtime_lower_threshold))
        matchtime_upper_threshold = self.default_upper_threshold
        print('Match time upper threshold is: {}' .format(matchtime_upper_threshold))
        
        print("Getting the required base tables")
        con = self.get_redshift_connection()
        cursor = con.cursor()
        self.getBaseTables(matchtime_lower_threshold,matchtime_upper_threshold,cursor)
        
        print("Getting the enriched dataset for incoming matches (the ones to be inserted or updated)")
        incomingMatchesFullDF = self.getIncomingMatchesFullData()
        print("Total records in incomingMatchesFullDF: ", incomingMatchesFullDF.count())
        
        print("Copying the incoming data to temp work dir")
        
        print("Clearing work directory: {}" .format(self.work_scad_path))
        self.deleteAllObjectsFromS3Prefix(self.dest_bucket,self.dest_work_prefix_scad)
        
        print("Writing data to work dir: {}" .format(self.work_scad_path))
        #.coalesce(1) \
        incomingMatchesFullDF.write \
                             .partitionBy("match_updated_date") \
                             .mode("overwrite") \
                             .parquet(self.work_scad_path + self.work_dir_partitioned_table_scad)
        print("Data copied to work dir")
        
        print("Reading data from work dir in a temporary dataframe")
        incomingMatchesFullDF_copy = self.spark.read.parquet(self.work_scad_path + "scm_case_alert_data_work.parquet/")
        
        if self.update_mode == 'overwrite':
            print("Datamart update mode is overwrite. New data will replace existing data.")
            print("Publishing to Redshift")
            self.publishToRedshift(con,cursor)
            print("Publishing to Redshift complete")
        
        elif self.update_mode == 'upsert':
            print("Datamart update mode is upsert. New data will be loaded and existing data will be updated.")
            
            print("Checking for cases updated between {} and {}" .format(matchtime_lower_threshold,matchtime_upper_threshold))
            updatedCasesDF = self.getUpdatedCases(matchtime_lower_threshold,matchtime_upper_threshold)
            updatedCasesDF.createOrReplaceTempView("updated_cases")
            
            print("Getting updated case attributes")
            updatedCaseAttributesDF = self.getUpdatedCaseAttributes()
            
            print("Moving updated case data to temp work directory: {}".format(self.work_updated_cases_path))
            
            print("Clearing work directory")
            self.deleteAllObjectsFromS3Prefix(self.dest_bucket,self.dest_work_prefix_updated_cases)
            
            try:
                print("Writing data to work dir: {}" .format(self.work_updated_cases_path))
                updatedCaseAttributesDF.coalesce(1) \
                                       .write \
                                       .mode("overwrite") \
                                       .parquet(self.work_updated_cases_path + "updated_cases.parquet")
            except Exception as e:
                e = sys.exc_info()[0]
                print("No data to write to work dir")
            
            print("Starting the process to publish data to Redshift")
            self.publishToRedshift(con,cursor)
            print("Publishing to Redshift complete")
        
        print('Updating metadata table')
        
        matchtime_lower_threshold_new = incomingMatchesFullDF_copy.agg({'match_updated_time': 'max'}).collect()[0][0]
        
        if matchtime_lower_threshold_new is not None:
            matchtime_lower_threshold_new_formatted = matchtime_lower_threshold_new.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            print("Latest match time lower threshold with new load: {}" .format(matchtime_lower_threshold_new_formatted))
            self.updatePipelineMetadata('scm_case_alert_data','max_data_update_time',matchtime_lower_threshold_new_formatted)
        else:
            print("No new matches, leaving max_data_update_time for match as it is")
        
        print("Metadata table up to date")
        
        print("Committing the updates to Redshift and closing the connection")
        con.commit() #Committing after the metadata table is updated to ensure the datamart data and threshold are aligned
        cursor.close()
        con.close()
```

**Spark History Server Screenshot:**
[image: DAG]
[image: Summary metrics]
[image: Tasks]

Answer (score 1):

As you have correctly felt, you're having data skew issues. This is really apparent from your last screenshot. Have a look at the shuffle read/write sizes! The thing that you have to find out is: for which shuffle operation (looks like a join) are you having this issue?

Only salting the large dataframes without knowing where your skew is wont solve the issue.

So, my proposed plan of action:

- You see that stage 112 from your picture is the problematic stage. Figure out which join operation this is about. In the [SQL tab](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html#sql-tab) of the web-ui you can find that stage 112 and hover over it. That should give you enough info to figure out which shuffle/join key is skewed.
- Once you know which key is skewed, understand the statistical contents of your key using `spark-shell` or something like that. Figure out which value is overly common. This will help in making future decisions. A simple `df.groupBy("problematicKey").count` will already be really interesting.
- Once you know that, you can go ahead and salt that specific key.

But you're absolutely on the right track! Keeping an eye on that Tasks page and the time it takes for each task is a great approach!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! On the SQL tab, I don't see stages however I can find the long running query from the completed queries section. I see two queries that took 1.5 hours


**count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0**
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:3045)

**parquet at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0**
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:874)

However, this only tells me the time taken is when I making taking a count of the records in my final dataframe produced by joining my 18 temp views and while writing the dataframe to S3.

Comment: And I already knew this because of the print statements I have put in between. I am still not able to find out the skewed dataset and the corresponding skewed attribute. And clicking on the query link opens up a DAG but again I am not able to pin point the problem.
May be I am missing something?

Comment: Ok great so when you click on the query link and see the DAG again, you should be able to hover (with your mouse) over each of the blocks in your DAG. While hovering, you'll see some details about the Datasets you're working with. I can't really look at the DAG for you, but hovering over all of the blocks in that stage should be able to help you to understand which piece of the code you're looking at. Good luck! :)